# ASP.NET MVC - cross sub domain authentication/membership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-membership, subdomain

Hit a roadblock while implementing a [sub domain based language switcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170008/building-a-language-switcher-2-languages-only-asp-net-mvc) (en.domain.com loads English, jp.domain.com loads Japanese).

**How do I get a single membership system to work across multiple sub domains (ASP.NET MVC C#)?**

Saw something about adding `domain="domain.com"` to `<forms >` entry in web.config. Did that, but does that work when testing on local visual studio development web server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forms Authentication across Sub-Domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608120/forms-authentication-across-sub-domains)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try creating the cookie yourself.

In *AccountController* you'll find this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
```

that "creates and adds to the cookie collection". It doesn't allow modification of the domain (but does allow modification of the path, oddly). Instead create a cookie without adding to the collection, modify the necessary properties, then add to the collection:

```
var a = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
//if you're debugging right here, a.Domain should be en.example.com; change it
a.Domain = "example.com";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(a);
```

James

Comment: Excellent idea... although I've already decided to scrap using sub-domains for language choice, this is one to remember. Thank you!

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm using EF6 MVC 4... do you have any tips plz?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use dot prefix, like this.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms domain=".tv.loc" loginUrl="~/signin" timeout="2880" name="auth" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: also, this only works for 2nd level domains or higher, i.e. `.mydomain` doesnt work, but `.mydomain.com` will

Comment: does it work for "localhost"? i.e. for debugging in VS?
Also is it required to set the domain in the form tag if you are setting the domain in the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is how browsers sends cookie during request.

Cookie is generally tied to a single domain, this is for security reasons and performance. For example, user don't want to send cookie for your domain to any other domain, because your cookie may contain sensitive information.

Browser do differentiate between cookies set with en.domain.com and jp.domain.com. They do not allow cookies from one domain goes to the other because they are not on a parent domain.

The solution to your problem would be to take over the control of generating cookies. I haven't played much with ASP.NET MVC, but I'm sure it can be done not through the HTML but through a property or something. This is a very common scenario. You should set the cookies domain to "domain.com" for your production boxes, that is correct. If you're working on a local box, you should set the cookies domain to "".