# Session transfer between domain and sub domain in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, form-authentication

Here is an article described how to share the authentication cookie between the domain and the sub domain: [ASP.NET MVC - cross sub domain authentication/membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181556/asp-net-mvc-cross-sub-domain-authentication-membership)

What I want is to switch users between domains.
For example there are two asp_membership database for the two domains. (The sub domain will run in a virtual directory.)
Now if user A1 log in to the main domain then while browsing the sub domain user A1 should be automatically authenticated. Provided users with the same name exists in both the databases.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions out there. But the easier solution is to use the same machine key for the two sites and same hashing algorithm for asp.net membership managements. That will do the trick.